# how to enter dynamic delay in tkinter so that the numbers printed on the screen appears after that delay

Tags: python, user-interface, timer, tkinter, delay

I want to introduce some delay in my code. I am using text.after() to get the delay but my tkinter window opens after that specified delay and the ouput is already printed on it.

Basically I am trying to replicate the functionality of sleep(), that is the lines of code should get executed before the timer starts. Then the timer should introduce 4 secs of delay and then the following lines of code should execute. I want to automate some test equipment and I want the next equipment to turn on after 4 secs of delay after the previous equipment was turned on.

To explain this situation, I will use a very simple code. I want the "Start Timer" to appear first. Then I want the numbers 1,2,3,4 appear on the tkinter GUI after 1 sec interval, like a timer going on from 1 to 4. Then I want "Stop Timer to appear".  In this way the execution of the code is delayed by 4sec in between.

Is there a way to do this ?

Here is my updated example code:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
def append_number(n):
    text.insert(END, str(n) + "\n")
    text.see(END)
    # add one, and run again in one second
    if n > 0:
    root.after(1000, append_number, n-1)

# start the auto-running function
text.insert(END, "Start Timer")
append_number(5)
text.insert(END, "Stop Timer")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: displaying a message every second for four seconds is a different problem from wanting a piece of equipment to turn on after four seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `after` to cause a function to run in the future. A simple solution is to call that immediately in the loop and schedule all of the updates:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
def append_number(n):
    text.insert(END, str(n) + "\n")
    text.see(END)

for i in range(1, 5, 1):
    root.after(i*1000, append_number, i)
root.mainloop()
```

Another common pattern is to have the function automatically reschedule itself, and then quit after a certain condition. For example:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
def append_number(n):
    text.insert(END, str(n) + "\n")
    text.see(END)
    # add one, and run again in one second
    if n < 4:
        root.after(1000, append_number, n+1)

# start the auto-running function
append_number(1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: My main purpose is to create a delay in the execution of my current code, so I just want to confirm that, if a call this function after few lines of my code then, I will have 4 secs of delay, and the following lines of the code will get executed. Is this correct. I am trying to replicate the functionality of sleep() in the GUI. Basically I am trying to automate few measurement equipment and I want to make sure there is some delay before the next equipment turns on.

Comment: I have edited my question, please check and let me know if there is a solution to this

Comment: Adding a delay in a GUI program makes no sense. GUIs are nearly always in a delayed state, so to speak -- GUIs are designed to wait for events. They aren't designed to freeze for a period of time. If you just want to turn on some piece of equipment after a period of time, use `after` to call a function after that period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Change the loop into a function that you can call and don't run a loop inside of it, instead keep track of the values as they change:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()

def updater(i, j):
    if i <= j:
        text.insert(END, i)
        text.insert(END, "\n")
        text.yview_pickplace("end")
        i += 1
        text.after(1000, updater, *[i, j])

root.after(1000, updater, *[0, 10])
root.mainloop()
```

This of course is a very general example that you will need to form to fit your own application.

Comment: My main purpose is to create a delay in the execution of my current code, so I just want to confirm that, if a call this function after few lines of my code then, I will have 4 secs of delay, and the following lines of the code will get executed. Is this correct. I am trying to replicate the functionality of sleep() in the GUI. Basically I am trying to automate few measurement equipment and I want to make sure there is some delay before the next equipment turns on.

Comment: I have edited my question, please check and let me know if there is a solution to this